# Deleting a HBitmap placed into a QLabel

Tags: qt, qlabel, hbitmap

I have a series of `QLabel` objects on my Qt GUI, and I fill them with HBITMAP objects.  These HBITMAP's are buffers in memory, they don't exist on disk.

Now I use the `QPixmap`s fromWinHBITMAP`to create a`QPixmap`which I can then pass to the`QLabel`s`setPixmap` function.

Now, the question is, what happens to the current image in the QLabel, when I overwrite it with another, does it stay in memory?  Does it get deleted?

I suspect it doesn't get deleted properly, as my program grows to enormous proportions after running for about an hour.  (1.7GB) in memory.

The code which does the conversion is:

```
//buffer is a map of QLabels which are filled with images.
void LoadPixmapFromBitmap(HBITMAP hBitmap, std::map<int, QLabel*>& buffer, int pixmapindex)
{
    QPixmap pix;
    pix = QPixmap::fromWinHBITMAP(hBitmap);

    QPixmap temp(pix);      
    QSize sz(164, 121);
    QPixmap resized(temp.scaled(sz));

    QMatrix rotation;
    rotation.rotate(90);
    QPixmap rotated = resized.transformed(rotation);

//an attempt to delete the previous image properly and put in a new one.  This doesn't seem to work.
    if (buffer[pixmapindex]->pixmap() != NULL)
    {
        HBITMAP hbtmp = buffer[pixmapindex]->pixmap()->toWinHBITMAP();
        buffer[pixmapindex]->clear();

        HDC dc = GetDC(this->winId());
        //HBITMAP p_old = SelectObject(dc, hbtmp);

        BOOL deleted = DeleteObject(hbtmp);
        if (!deleted)
            PrintMsg("temp not deleted");
    }

//////////////////////////////////end of attempt
    buffer[pixmapindex]->setPixmap(rotated);

    BOOL success = DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    if (!success)
        PrintMsg("hBitmap was not deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QPixmap::fromWinHBITMAP` make a copy of given bitmap, not alias one.

You should delete original bitmap just after conversion to `QPixmap`, because call to `oWinHBITMAP` makes a copy (*again*) of bitmap, storied in given pixmap, but not gives you handle to original windows bitmap.

Comment: I have a call to `DeleteObject` with a handle to the original bitmap at the end of the above function, is that enough?

Comment: @TonyTheLion, should be. Also drop all that conversion `toWinHBITMAP`. It actually no use